# Approximation of a sum within an exponential

Tags: approximation

There is a well-known equation in international economics, called
the gravity equation. This equation expresses imports from a country
as a function of importer size, exporter size, and distance. In particular,
$$
X_{ij}=\frac{Y_{i}Y_{j}}{\tau_{ij}}
$$
Here, the LHS measures the value of imports by $i$ from~$,$$\tau_{ij}$
represents distance between $i$ and $j,$$Y_{i}$ represents $i's$
size and~$Y_{j}$ represents $j's$ size., Now, in a regression framework,
one estimates this equation in additive form:
$$
lnX_{ij}=lnY_{i}+lnY_{j}-ln\tau_{ij}+\epsilon_{ij}
$$
where $\epsilon_{ij}$ is a random measurement regression error term.
The OLS predicted values one obtains are defined as $\widehat{lnX_{ij}}$.
As always, the hats denote the orthogonal projection of $X_{ij}$
onto the space spanned by $Y_{i},Y_{j}$ and $\tau_{ij}.$Without
getting into the details of the procedure, one wishes to add over
all the trading partners for a country $i,$ after exponentiating
this expression. In other words, total\emph{ predicted} imports by
$i$ are
$$
\sum_{j\neq i}exp\left(\hat{\beta}_{1}lnY_{i}+\hat{\beta}_{2}lnY_{j}+ln\tau_{ij}\right)
$$
 The expression above is quite complicated. If there were no exponential,
this would be easily simplified. Can this be approximated by a linear
function, or any function that allows me to say collect terms that
don't involve $j$ , and just make this expression more tractable?
I feel that this question is not apt for the economics forum, as the
question is not about the economics.

Comment: [For large $N$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum), $\sum_{j=1}^Nu_j\approx\int_0^Nu_jdj$ can be a good approximation, but whether the integral's more tractable than the sum when $u_j=\exp(a_j+b_j+c_j)$ depends on $a_j+b_j+c_j$.

Comment: Perhaps a taylor series approximation could do the trick? Actually maybe not, because the derivative of the exponential is also the exponential..

Comment: Maybe we can help you more if you show [how this problem came up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: Right, will try to modify it accordingly.

Comment: Are you trying to estimate the $\beta_k$ ? But why are they not just $1$, according to the initial equation ? If true, you can resort to the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm.

Comment: Why does $\ln \tau_{ij}$ has a plus sign ?

Comment: Should be minus, thanks.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, they should be in theory, but don't always hold in the data.

Comment: Could you answer my first question ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust- Yes, the \beta are not 1 in the data. The estimation itself is not the problem, it is just the simplification of the final expression I am after.

Comment: I think I can go with a Maclaurin series expansion

Comment: Isn't it more traditional to apply least-squares to the exponents used here, i.e. to minimize the product of the exponentials instead of their sum?